# Application restart and activity hiding

Tags: android, android-activity

I have application with two activities: SplashActivity and MainActivity. SplashActivity is the launch activity, it start for few seconds, close and launch MainActivity. MainActivity contains all application logic.

When user minimize application by Home button, then doesn't using application some time and maximize it again, data in my application is expired and I need to restart application. I make it with onStart in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (dataIsExpired()) {
        finish();
        Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

It working well, but before SplashActivity launched I see MainActivity with old data for few moments. Is there way to restart without previous activity showing?

I don't need to clear it manually, I just need to restart whole app.

Comment: Don't place the code inside `onStart()` but place it at `onRestart()` or `onCreate()`

Comment: @Strider, thank you, but it doesn't help.

Comment: When are you making `dataIsExpired()` true? just `finish()` your activity at the same time,

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` your activity in `onPause()` or `onStop()` of `MainActivity` so that it will be removed when minimising the app and will launch fresh.

Comment: No, I can't, because if user minimize app for short time, data will not expired and I restart is not needed.

Comment: here i see the reason is you have written the logic for checking data expiry in onStart() of MainActivity. By the time this code executes, your activity appears.